# Do not chain ordinary method call after safe navigation operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I am unable to find the problem with this rubocop warning
`Do not chain ordinary method call after safe navigation operator.`

```
price_array = user&.user_price_fluctuation&.market_price&.sort << user_price&.sort
```

Comment: I would call it a code smell when there are so many safe navigation operations in a chain. Some would even say that such long method chains even without safe navigation would be a code smell because it violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 9):

Just think about what the safe navigation operator does: it evaluates to `nil` if the object the method is being called on is `nil`.

So, if `foo` is not `nil`, then `foo&.bar` will call `bar` on `foo`, but if `foo` is `nil`, then `foo&.bar` is `nil`, too.

That is why it does not make sense to chain an ordinary method call after the safe navigation operator:

```ruby
foo&.bar.baz
```

If `foo` is not `nil`, this will work, but if `foo` is `nil`, then `foo&.bar` is also `nil` and you are trying to call `nil.baz`, which does not work. In other words: the code only works if you already know that `foo` is not `nil`, but then you would not need the safe navigation operator in the first place!

The same is true for your code: if any if `user` or any of the intermediate values in the chain is `nil`, then you are calling `nil << something`, which does not work. You need to make sure the *whole chain* uses the safe navigation operator:

```ruby
price_array = user&.user_price_fluctuation&.market_price&.sort&.<<(user_price&.sort)
```

Of course, the even *better* solution is to forget about the safe navigation operator and instead figure out where those `nil` values are coming from in the first place and fix it.